# How to create a horizontal list in bullet points MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, bullets

I am using Office 365, MS Word. I need to create a bullet points list horizontally. But in all the places where I searched, it gave me the option of adding a table with one row and including the content in each column. This is a hectic process as I have many bullet point lists to be converted into horizontal lists in my Word document. Is there any other way of creating horizontal bullet points in MS Word?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Find and Replace to swap the paragraph return or line break before your bulleted item with the symbol you'd like to use for the bullet and as many spaces before and after as you need.  It won't be a bullet pointed list as far as word is concerned, but it will look like one.

Answer (score 0):

There's at least 3 ways to create the graphic impression of a horizontal bulleted list.

1. You can use a Table (as you've already discovered)
2. You can use Tabs
3. You can use Columns

[image: examples]

In the first two examples, you're creating a visual representation of a bulleted list, but Word "knows" that it's not a list.

In the third example, you create an actual list which is displayed across columns to create the horizontal appearance.  However, Word knows it's a list, and you can treat it as such (e.g. change numbering or bullets globally).

Regardless of the methodology you choose, you're using Word in a manner it's not specifically designed for, so it'll take extra work to format the way you want.  The best option for repeating is to set one "list" up as a template and paste that wherever you want the effect.  Than you can just replace the template values with your actual values.